# Shortcut to declare alignment of many columns in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Suppose I have a table with 20 columns that should all be centered. Is there a way to declare the alignment without literally counting out 20 `c`'s? Something like `c{20}` might be the syntax. I feel like I saw this once, but I can't find a reference anywhere.

Comment: Use the `array` package, and write the specifiers as `{*{20}{c}}` instead of `{ccc…cc}`.

Comment: @Bernard: There is no need for [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) here, although it is a good addition to any document.

Comment: @Werner: ? I thought it was defined in array. Never checked though.

Comment: @Bernard: Then check. :)

Comment: @Werner: 'f course, I trust you. I just meant never thought of checking:).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Replication of column specifications is done using a `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` interface, which should repeat `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{20}{c}}
  % tabular content
\end{tabular}
```

will produce a table of 20 columns, each one centred. To add vertical column rules ([which you should never do](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)), you can use

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{20}{c|}}
  % tabular content
\end{tabular}
```

Note how the replication only includes a single right-side vertical rule with a single left-side rule at the beginning. One could also have used `*{20}{|c}|`.

Comment: The second form behaves slightly more oddly with `\multicolumn`?

Comment: @cfr: Yes; this is because of the insertion of the rules. I forget which (left/right), but they are associated with that particular column.

Comment: yet, be careful in using |. See the `booktabs` manual for a nice introduction into nice tables :) https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs