# Columns are not the same width in a table

Tags: tables, columns, width

I have the following code for a table, but I can't figure out why 2 columns are wider:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2em}}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption[]{\footnotesize\textbf{The initial conditions for Honeybee embryos.}}
\label{table: initial target bee}
\resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Genes} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Initial values in Regions} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Target values in Regions}\\
\cline{2-9}
& R1 & R2 & R3 & R4 & R1 & R2 & R3 & R4  \\
\hline
\emph{e}& 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: don't use `[h]` !! it usually generates a warning and latex changes it to `[ht]` but better to use `[htp]` to avoid teh float going to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. You defined a `newcolumntype` C but used a small c in the column specifiers is the main error. Also, you might want to consider extend the `arraystretch` a bit via

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 1.5 can be adjusted to sue one's need.
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption[]{\footnotesize\textbf{The initial conditions for Honeybee embryos.}}
\label{table: initial target bee}
\resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{|C}|}%|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Genes} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Initial values in Regions} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Target values in Regions}\\
\cline{2-9}
& R1 & R2 & R3 & R4 & R1 & R2 & R3 & R4  \\\hline
\emph{e}& 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I took that commend from somewhere else, but I didn't know how it works.

Comment: @Maryam -- I see. Whenever you use a newcolumntype command to define a style for specific column(s), it is supposed to be used in the column specifier.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the spanning `\multicolumn` is wider than the collective widths of the spanned columns. In those cases, the last column stretches to fill the wider `\multicolumn`. The way around this is to stretch the columns to make room (you've already defined a `C`-column for this):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2em}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Genes} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Initial values in Regions} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Target values in Regions} \\
  \cline{2-9}
  & R1 & R2 & R3 & R4 & R1 & R2 & R3 & R4  \\
  \hline
  \emph{e} & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c*{8}{C}}
  \toprule
  \smash{\raisebox{-.55\normalbaselineskip}{Genes}} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Initial values in Regions} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Target values in Regions} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
           & R1  & R2  & R3  & R4  & R1  & R2  & R3  & R4 \\
  \midrule
  \emph{e} & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.7 &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The latter table doesn't require [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow), but it does require the awesome [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Also note the short-hand column specification (see [Shortcut to declare alignment of many columns in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192564/5764)).

Answer (score 1):

Typesetting good tables requires some hand work. For numeric tables I'd recommend `siunitx`, which provides amazing features with its `S` columns.

For the particular problem, increasing the `\tabcolsep` seems to give good results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.1]}
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.0]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Genes &
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Initial values in Regions} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Target values in Regions} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(l){6-9} % no trimming at the right
         & {R1} & {R2} & {R3} & {R4} & {R1} & {R2} & {R3} & {R4} \\
\midrule
\emph{e} & 0.7  & 0.7  & 0.7  & 0.7  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The change to the parameter will not propagate, because it's in a `table` environnment.

There is also no need to lower “Genes”: it's a heading at the same level as the other first level headings. The first column should be left aligned.

In the specification for the `S` columns, you tell the number of digits in the integer and in the decimal part.

[image]