# A four column table shows an extra column

Tags: tables, multicolumn, columns

I am planning on using a piece of code from https://www.sharelatex.com website. It is a table with four columns.

Here is the code snippet:

---

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name     or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 Code&ISO numeric Code\\
 \hline
 Afghanistan   & AF    &AFG&   004\\
 Aland Islands&   AX  & ALA   &248\\
 Albania &AL & ALB&  008\\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA&  012\\
 American Samoa&   AS  & ASM&016\\
 Andorra& AD  & AND   &020\\
 Angola& AO  & AGO&024\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

---

[image]

My question is, how do I get rid of this extra column right after the first as illustrated in the image above?

Comment: It is not an extra column, but double vertical line defined by `...p{3cm}||p{3cm}...`

Comment: Just rephrasing @PrzemysławScherwentke 's comment:  you just need to replace `||` by `|` in order to get a single vertical line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite of this question has been answered in comments and questions like this have been discused before in this community many times, I am amswering it just in order to improve a little bit the code and to show a couple of things regarding tables:

1. It is strongly recommended to avoid vertical lines (see [Small Guide
   to Making Nice
   Tables](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf)).
2. The table can be placed in `table` environment to make it float,
   like in `figure` environment, so it also can have its own caption.
   (See [Tables in LaTeX2ε: Packages and
   Methods](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf)).
3. The `\usepackage{booktabs}` loads `array` and it is a ver powerful
   package for tables. It also permits the usage of *rules* in other
   array-like environments (ibidem, page 9.).
4. The arguments `!htpb` between brackets, specify placement in float
   objects like tables. (See [this
   answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/125434)).
5. To avoid repetitive and tedious declarations in case of multiple
   columns like `{cccccccccccc}`, one can write a brief and simple
   notation `*{12}{c}`. (See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192568/125434))

---

### Improved visualization of table

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Country List}} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Country Name \\ or Area Name\end{tabular}}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}ISO ALPHA\\ 2 Code\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}ISO ALPHA\\ 3 Code\end{tabular}} & \textbf{ISO numeric Code} \\ \midrule
Afghanistan                                                                              & AF                                                         & AFG                                                        & 004              \\
Aland Islands                                                                            & AX                                                         & ALA                                                        & 248              \\
Albania                                                                                  & AL                                                         & ALB                                                        & 008              \\
Algeria                                                                                  & DZ                                                         & DZA                                                        & 012              \\
American Samoa                                                                           & AS                                                         & ASM                                                        & 016              \\
Andorra                                                                                  & AD                                                         & AND                                                        & 020              \\
Angola                                                                                   & AO                                                         & AGO                                                        & 024              \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could mention `*{3}{c}` as an alternative to `ccc` here as well (which is not a reduction concerning the number of characters but in case of having `cccccccccccc` `*{12}{c}` it would be simpler ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course! I will include it. In the post. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is there any question of yours that I can mention in the further edit, that contains what you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: No question concerning the `*{}{c}` syntax by me. But there are a lot of them, I am pretty sure

Comment: @ChristianHupfer A shame. Ok, I will search for an appropiate one.